# Is access pipe leading to water main stop valve at curb physically attached to water main?

Tags: water, shutoff

I'm in Philadelphia, PA. I'm unable to get a key around the stop valve, because it's at an angle. It's several feet down, and I'd like to know if I can dig out and re-position the access pipe to correct the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "access pipe"? Is it a plastic box with a plastic cover you can remove? Can you post a picture?

Comment: I think the technical name is "curb stop box." It's the pipe at the street leading down to the main water shut off valve. It's cast iron, 4" diameter at the top, tapering to about 2" the rest of the way down. It has a cast iron cover that says "water" on it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure about Philly, but all the ones I have seen were just a casing not connected to the water pipes.You may be able to probe around with a long screwdriver or probe of some sort to see if you feel dirt where the pipe goes in and out.

Comment: Thanks, Gwydionforge. I'm going to try that. Hopefully, I can re-position or replace the pipe.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my water valve access so i called the water company and they fixed it while I was at work. They told me that the valve and access to it was their responsibility  and the piping after the valve was my responsibility.

Comment: I second @d.george.  Typically utility company owns the valve and all piping to it so they would be the ones responsible for accessibility.  Admittedly in some municipalities, you are not suppose to operate the valve either; the utility company is because they own the valve.  When we did winterizations for banks the utility company was adamant we were not allowed to turn their valve off and vowed to fine anyone operating their valve.  I have never experienced or heard of any follow through in this though.

Comment: Thanks, d.george and Damon. The folks at PWD have been ignoring me so far, but I'll try to pin them down on what they're actually willing to take responsibility for. Their website insists that everything beyond the main pipe is the owner's problem, so it will be a pleasant surprise if they're willing to fix it.

Comment: Finally reached someone at PWD, after 15 minutes on hold. They rudely informed me that their only responsibility is the main pipe in the street and the meter in your house. Yeay, Philly. Taxes out the wazoo, and no services.

Comment: I would call the utility and tell them that I have a problem inside my home and that they need to turn off that utility until the problem can be fixed. Then they can turn the utility back on.

Comment: d.george - you'd think that would work, right? I can already guess what they'd say: First, unless it's an emergency, they probably won't come without charging you for it. Second, if they get here and can't reach the valve, it's your responsibility to correct it. Not worth the headache dealing with this city. Have shovel, will dig.